# Java - KeyEvent variable

Tags: java, awtrobot

So. I got a little problem. Most likey caused because Im very new to java. Anyways, my question is:
Why does this not work?

```
public static void pressKey(KeyEvent key) throws AWTException {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.key);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.key);
}
```

How would I get something like this to work? It would make my life alot easier.
thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no public static field called `key` in `KeyEvent` that's why

```
//just pass they argument to your method as argument to those methods
r.keyPress(key);
r.keyRelease(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
 public static void pressKey(int key) throws AWTException {
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(key);
    r.keyRelease(key);
}
```

for it to work

Comment: The method keyPress(int) in the type Robot is not applicable for the arguments (KeyEvent)

Comment: Now if I use 
`pressKey(KeyEvent.VK_C);` I get
`The method pressKey(KeyEvent) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Answer (score 0):

That 'key' variable is an integer. A KeyEvent is just an easy-to-remeber way to use it, but **both are integers**.

It means the method uses an **integer**, not a **KeyEvent**.

Let's say we have the following method:

```
public static void press(int event) throws AWTException {
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.keyPress(event);
    bot.keyRelease(event);
}
```

It could be called by two ways: the KeyEvent and an integer. All the same (don't forget to add a 'throws' statement or a 'try/catch'):

```
press(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
```

Or:

```
press(46);
```

If I'm right, both would send a slash (correct me if I'm wrong). But KeyEvents are way easier.

Also, keep in mind that not all keyboards have the same layout. Depending on the key, a completely different key would be sent, or worse, the robot would throw an IllegalArgumentException. I recommend you use Alt codes for characters that are not letters/numbers.